# temando error when we tried to edit/add products in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions

When we tried to edit/add products, we are getting following error in magento

Source model "temando/entity_attribute_source_packaging_mode" not found for attribute

"temando_packaging_mode"

Comment: Please do not edit a question in order to ask another. Just... ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You installed an extension which added a new attribute with this source model.

Then you deleted the extension without removing the attribute. Delete the attribute, problem solved.

You can lookup the attribute in table eav_attribute and catalog_eav_attribute.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for your reply. Can i delete attributes in admin panel, is it required to delete in database also?

Comment: Depends on whether the attributes are exposed in the manage attributes admin panel to be manipulated and if the admin panel doesn't crash for the same reason the add/edit products function is crashing. Getting familiar with phpMyAdmin in the end will probably be your only way.

Answer (score 3):

Run `delete from eav_attribute where source_model like "temando%"` to remove all attributes added by extension.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. we can delete in admin panel only, Is it enough or is it mandatory to edit in database also

Comment: Hi,  if you can delete them from Admin, it's OK.  But some programmatically added (via module install) attributes can be deleted from the database only.